# Django foreign keys - one class has the same relationship to multiple other classes

Tags: django, django-models, modeling

I have a model with three classes: `PendingAuthorisation`, `Director`, and `Member`. `Director` and `Member` instances are considered inactive if they have a corresponding `PendingAuthorisation`.

My problem is quite how to model this. I would ideally like `PendingAuthorisation` to have just one field, `defers`, which can refer to either a `Director` or a `Member`. If I create a foreign key in both `Director` and `Member` then I need to have two differently-named relations, and when using a `PendingAuthorisation` I would need to check both to find the object it is deferring. In no case should a `PendingAuthorisation` be deferring one object of each type.

Any suggestions on how to model this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend having two foreign keys (with a sanity check in your save method to make sure that they're not both set), and then a property to return back the object that's set.

Think about something like:

```
from django.db import models

class PendingAuthorization(models.Model):
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director, null=True, blank=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.director and self.member:
            raise ValueError, 'Both a director and member are set; this is not allowed.'
        return super(PendingAuthorization, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def defers(self):
        if self.director:
            return self.director
        if self.member:
            return self.member
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I'll head off to read into those features new to me.